# syntax error phpmyadmin when i run the command

Tags: syntax, phpmyadmin

syntax error phpmyadmin

CREATE TABLE `students`.`personal` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE , `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `age` INT NOT NULL CHECK(`age`>=18),`gender` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,`phone` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,`city` NOT NULL DEFAULT 'agra');

Comment: Where did you get the SQL command? Is this something that phpMyAdmin was trying to execute or some code you found somewhere that you copied and pasted in to an existing database? What is the rest of the error message? You really haven't given us enough information to help here.

Answer (score 0):

After minor fixes it should work.

- `id` should always be `primary key`
- you have missed the size in `city` column

```sql
CREATE TABLE students.personal (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL CHECK (age >= 18),
    gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'agra'
);
```